# Stuck at grabbing Novel title and its link in Python Web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Trying to scrape articles categories wise but stuck at grabbing Novel name and its URL.

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

site = "https://readlightnovel.org/"
r = get(site, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)"})
html_content = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")
category = soup.findAll(class_="search-by-genre")

all_categories = []
for link in soup.findAll(href=re.compile(r'/category/\w+$')):
urls = site + "category/" + link.text
all_categories.append(urls)
#print(urls)
for category in all_categories:
r = get(category, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)"}).content
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(r, "lxml")
Novel_name = soup.findAll("headline")
print(Novel_name)
```

Comment: Please ensure your indentation is correct before pasting in your code because it will make it a lot easier for others to read because this makes it difficult when trying to determine what code below your for loops is actually meant to be in the loop

Answer (score 0):

This code will give you a list containing all of the novel titles:

```
site = "https://readlightnovel.org/"
req = get(site, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'lxml')
category = soup.findAll('h1', {'itemprop' : 'headline'})

titles = [title.get_text() for title in category]
print(titles)
```